# Font file name error "APT0003 Invalid file name: It must contain only [^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+."

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, maui

After creating a Maui app I got an error which says "APT0003 Invalid file name: It must contain only [^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+."

I tried to rename the file to acceptable name but nothing seems to work. Any recommendations?

[image][image]

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version? Have you considered updating? You might be affected by this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3896

Comment: I’m seeing the same with Visual Studio 17.8. Seems like a regression bug.

Comment: I’m seeing the same with Visual Studio 17.8.7, but with update 17.9.2 is all right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing that solved the problem is updating the Visual Studio version. Also Android has issues with "-" in file names which is a problem because the default naming is with it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the template is wrong

Try this.

1 - Close VS Studio or unload your project.
2 - Edit the file .csproj. Make a backup copy of this file before.
3 - Look for the lines that include the commands to "Remove" the .ttf files, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiFont Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
  <MauiFont Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
  <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf" />
</ItemGroup>
```

4 - Erase them.
5 - Now, Replace this :

```
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

with this :

```
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

6 - If you have changed the name of the files that VS places by default (appicon and splash), you must put the names you used.
7 - Save the file
8 - Reload the project again.

Adicionaly, i recommend that when you add or modify resources, verify that Items Groups do not appear that remove the new resources. Sometimes VS generates some orders with this problem, and it is necessary to check the .csproj project file manually. Remember, make a backup copy of this file first always.

I hope to help you

Comment: Visual Studio 17.9.2 work!

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio and rename it in File Explorer (or whatever you want to use).

I'm going to guess that error message with the RegEx isn't taking into consideration that it's already doing a negative (`[^...]`) match because that RegEx pattern means:

- `[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+.`

  - Match any character **not** present in the list `[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]`

    - `+` matches one or more times
    - `a-z` matches any character from `a` to `z`
    - `A-Z` matches any character from `A` to `Z`
    - `0-9` matches any character from `0` to `9`
    - `_` matches `_` literally
    - `.` matches `.` literally
  - `.` matches any character

In other words, you would need to give a name consisting of **0** alphabetical characters, **0** numeric characters, and without `_` and `.`. Instead, I'm going to bet that you are **only allowed** to use `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and `.`. Just close out of VS and rename it in a different app. It's probably a bug.

Comment: The thing that solved the problem is updating the Visual Studio version. Also Android has issues with "-" in file names which is a problem because the default naming is with it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Issue to create a new Maui Project, I installed an Extention called .NET Upgrade Assistant and as soon as I disabled it and restarted the VS, the issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it fixed it for me. It was when using a new .Net MAUI template in .Net 8:

1. Create a backup of your csproj-file
2. In the csproj-file look for this:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiFont Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
      <MauiFont Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

3. If you have already an `ItemGroup` where the children start with `<None`, Copy-Paste the two lines

```
      <MauiFont Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
      <MauiFont Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf" />
```

to that `ItemGroup` and replace the `MauiFont` with `None`. It may look like this:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Fonts\GlacialIndifference-Bold.otf" />
      [...]
    </ItemGroup>
```

If the `None`-ItemGroup not exists, create it by yourself.

4. Save the file. Error gone.